# Inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER exception

Tags: sql, oracle

```
trim(TO_CHAR(COALESCE(FEE, 0), '$99999990.99')) as FEE
```

This is giving inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER exception.

FEE is a column of type NUMBER. Using Oracle db.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) What is the type of `FEE`?

Comment: Why do you think the error comes from that code snippet? What is the exact and FULL text of the error message? If FEE is indeed of NUMBER data type, then the error (at least the way you transcribed it) is unlikely to come from this piece of your code.

Comment: p.s. you don't need the `trim` if you add `FM` at the start of the number format, e.g. `'fm$99999990.99'`. Also, you should consider using non-specific locale formats, e.g. `'fmL99999990D99'`.

Answer (score 0):

The two parameter in COALESCE should be of the same type. Here maybe FEE is not a number. Even if it is '1', it is considered as char and '0' is expected.
Then there won't be an error in your specified case.